# create field group in hook_install()

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the [field_group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module and want to programmatically create groups of fields in the hook_install of my module.install file.

It seems that field_group doesn't have much of an api that can be used by other modules. Does anyone know of a way that I can create a field group and assign field types to it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own function to do this (works for me, YMMV):

```
/**
 * Create a field group.
 *
 * The field_group module does not come with an API that can be used by other
 * modules. This method fakes a Drupal new group form submission to create the
 * new group.
 *
 * @param  array  $group
 */
function _field_group_create_group(array $group) {

  drupal_load('module', 'field_group');
  module_load_include('inc', 'field_group', 'field_group.field_ui');

  $defaults = array(
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'mode' => 'form',
    'parent' => '',
    // TODO: default to heaviest weight
    'weight' => '',
    'format' => array('type' => 'fieldset'),
    'fields' => array()
  );

  $group = $group + $defaults;

  $form = array(
    '#entity_type' => $group['entity_type'],
    '#bundle' => $group['bundle'],
    '#view_mode' => $group['mode'],
    '#groups' => array()
  );

  $form_state = array(
    'values' =>  array(
      'fields' => array(
        '_add_new_group' => array(
          'group_name' => $group['group_name'],
          'label' => $group['label'],
          'parent' => $group['parent'],
          'parent_wrapper' => array('hidden_name' => '_add_new_group'),
          'weight' => $group['weight'],
          'format' => $group['format'],
        )
      )
    )
  );

  foreach ($group['fields'] as $field_name) {
    $form_state['values']['fields'][$field_name] = array(
      'parent' => '_add_new_group',
    );
  }

  field_group_field_overview_submit($form, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer is correct here, but I can't comment on it. There's a couple "bugs" in it. The following changes were made to make it work with the object/array that gets exported when using `field_group_load_field_group()`

Specifically, I changed this line:

`'format' => array('type' => 'fieldset'),`

To:

`'format' => array('type' => $group['format_type']),`

And:

`foreach ($group['fields'] as $field_name) {`

To:

`foreach ($group['children'] as $field_name) {`

The final code:

```
/**
 * Create a field group.
 *
 * The field_group module does not come with an API that can be used by other
 * modules. This method fakes a Drupal new group form submission to create the
 * new group.
 *
 * @param  array  $group
 */
function _field_group_create_group(array $group) {

  drupal_load('module', 'field_group');
  module_load_include('inc', 'field_group', 'field_group.field_ui');

  $defaults = array(
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'mode' => 'form',
    'parent' => '',
    // TODO: default to heaviest weight
    'weight' => '',
    'format' => array('type' => $group['format_type']),
    'fields' => array()
  );

  $group = $group + $defaults;

  $form = array(
    '#entity_type' => $group['entity_type'],
    '#bundle' => $group['bundle'],
    '#view_mode' => $group['mode'],
    '#groups' => array()
  );

  $form_state = array(
    'values' =>  array(
      'fields' => array(
        '_add_new_group' => array(
          'group_name' => $group['group_name'],
          'label' => $group['label'],
          'parent' => $group['parent'],
          'parent_wrapper' => array('hidden_name' => '_add_new_group'),
          'weight' => $group['weight'],
          'format' => $group['format'],
        )
      )
    )
  );

  foreach ($group['children'] as $field_name) {
    $form_state['values']['fields'][$field_name] = array(
      'parent' => '_add_new_group',
    );
  }

  field_group_field_overview_submit($form, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, all can be done this way:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1425984

```
function mymodule_install() {
// Add fieldgroup:
  $group_name = 'group_bankverbindung';
  $entity_type = 'profile2';
  $bundle = 'organizer_data';
  $mode = 'form';
  if (!field_group_exists($group_name, $entity_type, $bundle, $mode)) {
    $group = (object) array(
      'identifier' => $group_name .'|'. $entity_type .'|'. $bundle .'|'. $mode,
      'group_name' => $group_name,
      'entity_type' => $entity_type,
      'bundle' => $bundle,
      'mode' => $mode,
      'label' => 'Bankverbindung',
      'weight' => '1',
      'children' => array(
        'field_foobar',
      ),
      'format_type' => 'fieldset',
      'format_settings' => array(
        'formatter' => 'collapsible',
        'instance_settings' => array(
          'description' => '',
          'classes' => '',
          'required_fields' => 1,
        ),
      ),
    );
    field_group_group_save($group);
    ctools_include('export');
    ctools_export_crud_enable('field_group', $group->identifier);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

My solution - works for me

```
function mymodule_install() {
//Field_group object
 $group = (object) array(
    'identifier' => 'group_attributes|node|article|form',
    'group_name' => 'group_attributes',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'story',
    'mode' => 'form',
    'label' => 'Attributes',
    'children' => array(),
    'weight' => '7',
    'format_type' => 'fieldset',
    'format_settings' => array(
      'formatter' => 'collapsible',
      'instance_settings' => array(
        'description' => '',
        'classes' => '',
        'required_fields' => 1,
      ),
    ),
  );
    module_load_include('module', 'field_group');
    module_load_include('module', 'ctools');
    ctools_include('export');
 $new = new stdClass();
        $new->group_name = $group->group_name;
        $new->entity_type = $group->entity_type;
        $new->bundle = $group->bundle;
        $new->label = $group->label;
        $new->parent_name = $group->parent_name;
        $new->children =$group->children;
         // The form.
        $new->id = NULL;
        $new->weight = $group->weight;
        $new->mode = 'form';
        $new->format_type = $group->format_type;
        $new->format_settings = $group->format_settings;
        $new->identifier = $new->group_name . '|' . $new->entity_type . '|' . $new->bundle . '|' . $new->mode;
        ctools_export_crud_save('field_group', $new);
}
```